# Huge pages on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, memory, memory-management, huge-pages

The Mac OS X mmap man page says that it is possible to allocate superpages and I gather it is the same thing as Linux huge pages.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html

However the following simple test fails on Mac OS X (Yosemite 10.10.5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <mach/vm_statistics.h>

int
main()
{
    void *p = mmap((void *) 0x000200000000, 8 * 1024 * 1024,
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_ANON | MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE,
                   VM_FLAGS_SUPERPAGE_SIZE_2MB, 0);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED)
        perror(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0xffffffffffffffff
Cannot allocate memory
```

The result is the same with `MAP_FIXED` removed from the flags and `NULL` supplied as the address argument. Replacing `VM_FLAGS_SUPERPAGE_SIZE_2MB` with `-1` results in the expected result, that is no error occurs, but obviously the allocated memory space uses regular 4k pages then.

What might be a problem with allocating superpages this way?

Comment: Are you sure that the address region space is able to use a superpage addressing schema ? Try with a null address first or try to remove `MAP_FIXED` to see.

Comment: Sorry, I'm surprised not having saw it. Please forgive me. I do not know OSX memory management too much, but it may be possible that this address is not available for superpaging either because superpaging is available only in some regions or not available in a region that is currently using a different paging size.

Comment: There is some kernel parameters available through `sysctl`, every page size related ones have value 4096 (vm.pagesize, hw.pagesize) on my 10.10.5. sysctl states that 1GBPAGE is available on hardware. It may be possible that the current kernel config don't permit to use some pagesize.

Comment: It's possible, but I'd like to know what it is then. Regarding `sysctl` indicating `1GBPAGE` availability, are you referring to the `machdep.cpu.extfeatures` value? Then if you take a look at the `machdep.cpu.features` value, the `PSE` flag there means that 2 MB pages are supported as well, at least by the CPU.

Comment: I have `1GBPAGE` on mine but no `PSE36`. All of this let me think that many things are ready there to support superpaging but something is missing in some configuration... lack of documentation...

Answer (score -1):

This minor modification to the posted example works for me on Mac OS 10.10.5:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <mach/vm_statistics.h>

int
main()
{
    void *p = mmap(NULL,
                   8*1024*1024,
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE,
                   VM_FLAGS_SUPERPAGE_SIZE_2MB, // mach flags in fd argument
                   0);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED)
        perror(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work on MBP "15 (2019) on macOS Catalina. Is there anything that needs to be paid special attention to or configured? I receive the same error as the thread poster.

Comment: @Patrick it might be that you just don't have any unused contiguous memory page that large left. the best time to test is right after booting, and the longer the system runs, the smaller is the chance of this actually working. also the more RAM you have, the bigger the chance of this working, and vice-versa. if you're the kind that never reboots your mac, and you tested this after several days of uptime, i'm not surprised if its not working for you.

Comment: @Patrick and it's not relevant how much free RAM you have (mostly*), instead it's relevant how fragmented your kernel's physical memory allocations are. and the longer your system runs, the more fragmented it becomes. hence the best time to test is right after booting.